# Динамическая ссылка

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, стоит такая задача: нужно изменять ссылку в зависимости от адреса предыдущей страницы, на который был юзер. Поясню: если юзер пришёл с текущего сайта - то перебрасывать по javascript:history.back(1) (назад), иначе(кто-то поделился ссылкой и юзер открыл её в новой вкладке, т.е. нет предыдущей страницы) - ссылка ссылается на главную, т.е. в корень. Как это реализовать на javascript? Спасибо :)

Comment: А вас только чистый яваскрипт интересует?
У меня варианты только с $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] или в самой ссылке передавать её, типа http://yousite.com/?from=link и это уже яваскриптом обрабатывать. Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста!

Comment: Интересно в первую очередь на js либо jQuery. Ссылка нигде не передаётся, просто нужно следить за историей и если предыдущая ссылка в истории из текущего сайта - то перебрасывать на неё, в противном случае - в корень. Принцип-то я и сам знаю, да вот как это грамотно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.referrer - вам нужно это.

**Дополнено.**

Ок.

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('http://'+location.host) == 0){
    //значит, пришли с текущего сайта
}
```